# How to disable status bar for a specific app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm developing an Android app. Where I want to disable the status bar, I mean when the app is opened. Then user can't access the status bar from that app. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't completely disable it due to security reasons, to get the same behaviour as Youtube or Games (statusbar hidden until you swipe down) you can enable immersive mode

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive

Comment: I got it. I also thought so. Btw Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The android documentation actually covers this. Here's the scratch code, and I've linked the exact page. Ensure you are using the method prescribed for API 16 and higher if you are developing in that. I hope this is what you were looking for.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this method.